# how to judge the code of html is changing a new line in IE6/7/8?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

My code:

```
<div id="box">
<p>
    123
</p>
<p>
    abc
</p>
</div>

<script>
     var html = document.getElementById("box").innerHTML;

     alert(html)  //you can the different HTMLString between IE6/7/8 and IE9/FF 

     for (var i = 0, len = html.length; i < len; i++) {
         var word = html.charAt(i)
         if(i == 0){
           alert(word=="\n")  // IE6/7/8: false .     IE9/FF:true     
         }
         if(i == 11){
           alert(word=="\n")  //Look at here in IE6/7/8, why is false ??????
         }
     }
</script>
```

when (i==11),the char of here in IE6/7/8 is chaning new line,but why shows false?

how to write I could know the code of html is changing a new line in IE6/7/8??

Comment: Have you used escape() and look at what is in the string?

Comment: I think the new-line character will be "\r\n" in IE, not just "\n".

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with conditional comments, like

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script>
     var html6 = document.getElementById("box").innerHTML;

     alert(html6)  //you can the different HTMLString between IE6/7/8 and IE9/FF 
     }
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

then repeat for 7 and 8. i'm not 100% sure that alert will work, but you get the jist of it.